# Android Button Customizing

Tags: android, android-button

Are there any other ways to customize buttons expect the XML tags? I don't know how I could make a button [like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrr8J.jpg)

Comment: Check out following link: http://icodefree.blogspot.in/2014/11/android-custom-button-example.html or http://www.dibbus.com/2011/08/even-more-gradient-buttons-for-android/

Comment: Glad to help you. Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say except XML tags, but have you ever heard of drawable?

By making your custom drawable background you can easily achieve, what you want.

Firstly create your own drawable file, where you specify background of the button:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#fa1414"
        android:endColor="#ad2b2b" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#201e21"/>

    <corners android:radius="12dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

Then set the background of the button to the drawable file:

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="36dp"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

Output:

[image: Button example]

The solution is very easy, you don't need to do anything programmatically and you can reuse it as much as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!